# Crashes after updating to XCode 6 beta

Tags: sigabrt, ios8, xcode6

I've just upgraded to XCode 6 (iOS 8 SDK) and I am getting the following warning and error in the console that did not occur in XCode 5 (iOS 7 SDK):

`2014-06-08 08:58:57.266 ColorChaos[3250:138871] SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
2014-06-08 08:59:27.303 ColorChaos[3250:138871] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil'`

The `SetAppThreadPriority` seems to be just a warning because the app continues to run, but a few seconds/touches in it crashes with the `NSInvalidArgumentException` error.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar after updating? The error is not occurring in my code (I don't think), it highlights the line in main.m with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should note I've just realised XCode 5 is still installed along side XCode 6 and I can still compile and run my code in that so it's not really an issue any more but it would still be nice to know if it can be fixed.

Comment: Is XCode crashing or your user code? For the former, file a bug to Apple.

Comment: It's my code. It's not a bug with XCode, just some issue with using the new SDK I assume.

Comment: Maybe you should extend your question. Currently I don't see how we could help you with the information given. Some code? Minimal example?

Comment: It really might be an issue in your source code as the new SDK for example do not accept, when you do not set certain priority for operation in your background thread, downloads or something...

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem. If you're running off an iOS simulator make sure it's set to iPhone 5 or above. Swift code won't run on iOS 4 which, I believe, is the default emulator device for XCode 6.